# how to connect one of my mongo container to another?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, replicaset

I want to use Typesense with Mongodb. To do so I first need to enable replicaset.
From what I read here and there, to achieve it with `docker compose`, it must be done in two steps, like this :

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: testDb
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb-config/mongod.test.conf:/etc/mongod.conf:ro
      - ./mongodb-config/keyfile:/test/keyfile
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    expose:
      - '27017'
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod 400 /test/keyfile
        chown 999:999 /test/keyfile
        exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$@
    command: mongod --replSet testRs --keyFile /test/keyfile --bind_ip localhost;

  mongosetup:
    image: mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    restart: 'no'
    entrypoint:
      [
        'bash',
        '-c',
        "sleep 10 && mongo admin --host mongodb:27017 -u root -p example --verbose --eval 'rs.initiate()'",
      ]
```

log from `mongosetup` :

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://mongodb:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T14:58:50.437Z"},"s":"D1", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20109,   "ctx":"js","msg":"Creating new connection","attr":{"hostAndPort":"mongodb:27017"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T14:58:50.440Z"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":23074,   "ctx":"js","msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"InternalError: couldn't connect to server mongodb:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongodb:27017 (192.168.0.2:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused","file":"src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/mongo.cpp","line":745}}
Error: couldn't connect to server mongodb:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongodb:27017 (192.168.0.2:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T14:58:50.441Z"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":23074,   "ctx":"js","msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"Location12513: connect failed","file":"src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp","line":537}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T14:58:50.441Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":22787,   "ctx":"js","msg":"MozJS GC heap stats","attr":{"phase":"prologue","total":4799817,"limit":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T14:58:50.444Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":22787,   "ctx":"js","msg":"MozJS GC heap stats","attr":{"phase":"epilogue","total":153,"limit":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T14:58:50.444Z"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":23074,   "ctx":"main","msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"Location12513: connect failed","file":"src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/proxyscope.cpp","line":310}}
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

There must be something wrong with my way to try to connect, because I can do that manually without any problem :

```bash
docker exec -it 0188651cfb4b5789e832226094dae48fb8efd92fc318ce7b0286312f9a3d81de bash 
root@0188651cfb4b:/# mongosh -u root -p example
test> rs.initiate()
{
  info2: 'no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set',
  me: 'localhost:27017',
  ok: 1
}
testRs [direct: other] test>
```

I must be missing something, and since I'm a beginner with docker & mongo, I'm stuck :(
Thanks for your help

Comment: share `mongodb-config/mongod.test.conf` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--bind_ip localhost` in the command of mongodb container tells mongo to listen on local interface only. Try to connect to it from mongosetup manually and you will face the same error.

Use `--bind_ip_all` option instead.

Comment: Thank you sir, I spent so much time on this that my eyes were sheding tears of blood